# how can i fire history command from c program/shell script?

Tags: shell, terminal, command

I tried from C programming but that gives error "sh: 1: 
history: not found".
my code of c programming

```
int main ()
{
   char command[50];
   strcpy( command,"history | tail -20" );
   system(command);
   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can access the environment variable $HISTFILE. Call the shell with the argument -ci. `-c` to run a command and `-i` to give the shell an interactive environment with all the available environment variables.

```
bash -ic 'tail -20 $HISTFILE'
```